# Something strange to me about the "dont" and the object of "épouvantait"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-relatifs

Below is the quote from ***Boule de Suif***:

> Ses armes, ses uniformes, tout son attirail meurtrier, ***dont*** elle épouvantait naguère ***les bornes des routes*** nationales à trois lieues à la ronde, avaient subitement disparu.

Why is the "dont" used here instead of "avec lequel" if the author was intended to express "by the means of deadly weapon or apparatus"? Also, the object of "épouvantait" is quite strange to me. Scare the borders or boundaries of the roads? That doesn't make any sense to me. Or do I misinterpret the meaning here? Please explain it to me in English, many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> La Garde nationale qui, depuis deux mois, faisait des reconnaissances très prudentes dans les bois voisins, fusillant parfois ses propres sentinelles, et se préparant au combat quand un petit lapin remuait sous des broussailles, était rentrée dans ses foyers. Ses armes, ses uniformes, tout son attirail meurtrier, dont elle épouvantait naguère les bornes des routes nationales à trois lieues à la ronde, avaient subitement disparu. (Guy de Maupassant, *Boule de suif*, 1880)

*Dont* can be used as a synonym of *avec lequel* when it stands for a thing and it introduces a defining relative clause expressing means.

[T.L.F.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/dont) (II. A. 3. b.)

> b) [Compl. circ. de moyen, d'instrument; l'antécédent désigne un inanimé] Synon. par lequel, avec lequel. *Son jeune disciple lui apporte la flûte dont il avoit coutume de jouer* (Staël, *Allemagne*,t. 3, 1810, p. 135) *Un rasoir dans la [main] droite dont il s'est coupé le cou* (Mérimée, *Lettres à M. Panizzi*,1870, p. 135)
>   *Madame Gide a fait confectionner de grandes housses en forme, dont on couvre les bibliothèques du palier, le matin, pendant l'heure du ménage...* Martin du Gard, *Notes sur André Gide*,1951, p. 1385.

In these example sentences found in the T.L.F *dont* stands for : *avec laquelle* (1st example), *avec lequel* (2nd example), *avec lesquelles* (3rd example). I do not know of a difference in register when one or the other is used.

In France the [*routes nationales*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_routes_nationales_de_France) is one of categories of roads that cross the country.  Milestones (*bornes*) are placed on the side of these roads at regular intervals (usually every kilometre) with such indications as number of the road and distance to the next village or city. They're about 65 cm high, 40 cm wide (haven't measured one, just looked at catalogues, they give different dimensions around those lines), the top is dome-shaped and red. You can see one on the picture illustrating [an article](http://www.20minutes.fr/societe/973977-20120719-routes-celebres-mythiques-france-route-nationale-7) on the famous *Nationale 7* (RN7) that goes from Paris to the Riviera.

The verb *épouvanter* is used in a metaphor in Maupassant's sentence. The gear was frightening to the people who saw it lying there on the milestones.

Comment: "Elle" here stands for "attirail"? But attirail is a masculine noun.

Comment: *Elle* stands for *La garde nationale*. You must look at the previous sentence. *Son attirail* is the gear of the garde nationale.

Comment: @xiexie *Boule de Suif* takes place in the 1870-1871 Franco-Prussian War. For the *garde nationale* at that time and its role in the Franco-Prussian war, see [this article in Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garde_nationale_fran%C3%A7aise_en_1870-1871). The *Garde Nationale* is something different nowadays.

Comment: Good answer, but can *dont* always be used as a synonym of *avec lequel* when expressing the means of something? What makes this sentence sound unusual is that even in that use-case, you can normally understand *dont* as standing for a noun that would be introduced by *de* -- I wonder if there are other examples

Comment: @qoba I expect it could. I haven't got anything on the matter at hand. What I know is that *dont* can often replace a compound relative pronoun with  [du/de la/des] quel(les) when the verb requires the preposition *de*. Always I wouldn't stake my life on it. *La  fille dont (de laquelle) je t'ai parlé*.  *Dont* is much more frequent and I know some  will make a difference between the two.in some cases. See the [BDQL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2904) for instance. I did not want to make a review in that question which was on a precise case (well, 2 actually...)

Comment: Ok - yes I agree about replacing *duquel* always - thinking about it more, *avec lequel* expressing means can't always be replaced by *dont*, for example one wouldn't say *le tournevis dont j'ai ouvert la boîte de conserve* * . I agree that the question doesn't call for a full review but suggest adding "sometimes" in "*Dont* can be used as a synonym of *avec lequel*" so that it's not read by a language learner as categorical permission to change one with the other.

Comment: Also I understand the metaphor differently from "The gear was frightening to the people who saw it lying there on the milestones." The text is humorously describing an army getting ready to fight an inexistent enemy, shooting at its own people by mistake, getting ready to war whenever a rabbit moves -- so their gear is meant to be frightening, but there's nobody to be frightened other than the milestones by the roadside, who it is pretty pointless to "frighten"...

Comment: @qoba You may... other interpretations will be found. I do not see any humour in this beginning. The people used to be frightened of the Garde Nationale which is now fleeing (and not ready to fight) a very real enemy: the Prussians who are getting near Rouen. The humour in this story is in the way the bourgeois  are depicted and that is later in the story.

Comment: Fair enough. I personally read it as the Garde Nationale previously being all over the countryside preparing for war and generally frightening everyone around, even the stones, as long as there was no enemy, but now that the enemy is actually approaching, they've retreated to their barracks... In any case, do you really think the metaphor is meant the weapons of the Garde Nationale were lying on the milestone? I hear it more as "they were so scary even the stones were scared".

Comment: I expect it can also be understood as you say, they frightened everybody, even the milestones, that's indeed subject to interpretation, but the fact they're fleeing from the enemy seems to me to be a historical fact, and that's how the story is usually explained.

Comment: I completely agree that they are fleeing. They were only ready as long as the enemy wasn't here, busy fighting rabbits, milestones, and inflicting friendly fire upon themselves... Which is to say that they weren't very ready at all. What I interpret differently is the gear being left lying on the milestones, as you mention in your answer. They had retreated to their barracks well ahead of the invasion... Are you saying that the retreat was so precipitous that they left their weapons behind? But *naguère* refers to the time before the retreat